# mongodb capped collections consume from offset

Tags: mongodb, capped-collections

We are considering using MongoDB capped collections as our fifo queues.
Our requirements are the following:

1. Processing of the messages should be done in insertion order
2. No messages should be lost/skipped
3. We should be able to start consuming from a specific offset

However we are facing the following issue:
Capped collections are guaranteeing read by insertion order. However the _ids are not guaranteed to be monotonic. 
This means that if there are multiple producers the following situation can occur:

```
[
  ...
  { 
    _id: 5b72f12599757c9e26c0946b,
    ...
  },
  { 
    _id: 5b72f12599757c9e26c0946d,
    ...
  },
  { 
    _id: 5b72f12599757c9e26c0946c,
    ...
  },
  { 
    _id: 5b72f12599757c9e26c0946e,
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

This means that if we start consuming with the following code:

```
const cursor = collection
  .find({ _id: { $gt: "5b72f12599757c9e26c0946d" } })
  .tailable()
  .cursor();
```

Then the message with 5b72f12599757c9e26c0946c will be skipped.

So my questions are the following:

1. Is it possible to guarantee monotonic ids on a capped collection?
2. Is it possible to start consuming from a specific offset without
   skiping messages with out of order _id?
3. Are we missing something?

Thanks in advance.